# Extracting Captions from streaming video

Tags: video-streaming, extract, subtitle, closed-captions

I am watching an educational online video and I would like to save the captions for reference later. I have tried snooping around with the web developer tools in chrome, but I don't really know what I am looking for.

How can I find the closed caption file and save it to my computer? In the case this isn't possible, is there a script I could run that would read the changes to the HTML as the captions appear, and save them? What would be your recommended approach to solving this problem?

(I have found [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877610/how-can-i-extract-captions-subtitles-from-this-streaming-video), but it didn't help. I couldn't find an .srt file in the Network log).

Thank you!

Comment: There are dozens of methods of encoding and transmitting captions, Including in the video stream itself. Without know the video you are looking at, there is now way to tell you what it is doing.

Comment: @szatmary How would I go about detecting the way the captions are transmitted? I know they are placed into an html element.